# Prove that the following grammar is ambiguous

Tags: ambiguous

S-> A|B|AB

A-> aA, B-> bB, A->€, B->€

€ is the empty string.

Find a string and show that it has two

a-) parse trees
b-) leftmost derivations
c-) rightmost derivations

Comment: How many empty strings (€) do you pay?

Comment: That is just a symbol € not a money symbol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're not gonna do your homework.

Build the parse tree using leftmost and rightmost derivations. If you can find any ambiguity, it is ambigious.

`S-> A|B|AB` is the key part. Try using both A, B and AB.

Comment: That is a sample of midterm question ı try to learn how to solve this question..

Comment: Well, there are three ways to parse the empty string, A->€, B->€ and AB -> €€ -> €

Comment: if you're happy with it as an answer, please mark it as the accepted answer